# Save result of promises inside an array with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing a script that should count elements in a JSON file. I can't figure out how to save results of promises in an array.

This is the async function that counts the elements:

```
async function countVulnerabilities(dir, project, branch) {
    await count[dir](new URL(path.join('/dropbox/sast/', project, branch, dir), process.env.REMOTE_DRIVE_PATH))
        .then((result) => {
            return result
        })
}
```

The function that calls it is this:

```
export function getLogs(req, res, id, project, branch) {
    let count = []
    if (checkMappedDrive()) {
        getDirs(project, branch)
            .then((dirs) => {
                dirs.forEach((dir) =>  {
                    countVulnerabilities(dir, project, branch)
                    .then((result) => {
                        count.push(result)
                        console.log(result)
                    })
                })
            })
            res.send(count)
    } else {
        res.send('Impossible to enstablish a connection with the remote drive')
    }
}
```

How can I push results in the `count` array? At the moment, it's returning `[]`.

Many thanks

Comment: Mixing `async` and `.then(...)` seems like a code-smell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I can return the response, I can't save it in an array...

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function countVulnerabilities(dir, project, branch) {
    return await count[dir](new URL(path.join('/dropbox/sast/', project, branch, dir), process.env.REMOTE_DRIVE_PATH))
}
```

what is count in this function?

Comment: Another function that counts elements in an object. But everything works there

Comment: but you there's nothing in count initially

Comment: ok tell me what this function is doing or you want it to do